# Update non-Periodic Calendar dates in control-m using excel

Tags: excel, calendar, control-m

I have business dates in excel sheet which have no rule base or specific pattern. In this case how to use excel directly to update different calendars of different application at once.

Comment: Welcome to SO.  This is not a free code-writing service but exists to help others with code or functions they are trying to develop.  As such, we expect to see clear cut questions with examples of data, attempted code, actual output, desired output, research efforts, etc. Please familiarize with how this site works by taking the [Two Minute Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Then read the HELP pages for information as to [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Control-M uses XML for import/export purposes.

See https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ph7OwlrNCfg as a starting point.